# Non-euclidean subring of $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling to think of any examples for this! Any idea on what subrings would fit the critera and *why* would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Does subring mean unitary subring or not?

Comment: Please don’t rely on the title to give information that is required to understand your query. Include it in the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples.

E.g. $R = \mathbb{Z}[3i]$ is not euclidean.

Because:

In $R$, we have $(1 + 3i)(1 - 3i) = 10 = 2 * 5$.

But $1 + 3i, 1 - 3i, 2, 5$ are all irreducible elements in $R$.

(Proof e.g. for $5$: if $5 = (a + 3bi)(c + 3di)$, then taking norm blah blah blah...)

Hence $R$ is not a UFD. Therefore not euclidean.

---

In general, if $p$ is an odd prime, then the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$ is $p + 1$ or $p - 1$, according to $p\equiv 1$ or $3 \mod 4$.

Hence $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$ will never be euclidean.

Comment: What do you mean with a class number of a ring which isn't a Dedekind domain?

Comment: @Wojowu It's the cardinal of its Picard group. In this setting, it's the group of invertible ideals modulo principal ideals.